# how are they doing this for their CMS?? And how can I do something similar

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, code

They've linked the CMS, mail (which is http://www.campaignmonitor.com), social sites management, some kind of online payment solutions, and word press all under one log-in.

I'm mostly a graphic designer -- 
People much smarter than me... How is this done?

Can anybody point me in the right direction to get something similar to this?.

here's a link of their youtube giving an overview of it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=eGKv8YDZvbo

Comment: I don't understand the bit about how to get something like this. They *are* the thing you're asking about. Can you clarify why you seem to be looking for an alternative? Free? Self-hosted? etc.

Comment: I like how it's how it's all linked under one login for the client. I would like to offer something similar to this to my clients. 

The ideal thing for me would be a simple open source CMS... so clients can easily change content, like even cushycms, and then include social sites management and able to get into wordpress all from the same log-in.

Answer (score 2):

They've basically made a mashup using the APIs of these various apps and services. You can "get" exactly that by signing up for their service.

If you want to build your own platform like that, then you need a programmer.

Comment: +1 though also see my response for a possible approach to assembling your own. Depending upon your own comfort, you might still need a developer, but it'd require significantly less if any full-on custom work.

Comment: @su: True. Now that I think about it, there are probably WP plugins for everything but social media management on that list--one of the good things about using such a popular platform.

Answer (score 1):

Many applications and services have produced plugins so that they integrate with WordPress, which they're including in TodayLaunch anyway. You could look into using WP as the core rather than their custom interface and bolt things onto *it*. The video doesn't say how much integration they do(it's not exactly in-depth), so some more complex tasks might require going directly to the extra application/service, but that's something you'll have to figure out in your own research.

As to why they include WordPress *and* their custom CMS thing, I have no idea. If you base your version on WP, there'd presumably be no reason for worrying about whatever that does.

Comment: Right now I'm mostly using wordpress as the core. As easy as wordpress is it's still a little complicated for a lot of my clients. So a simple (perferably open source) cms is very appealing to me. With wordpress added in as a blog and able to log in to all of it from one login. The social media management looks very slick too http://todaypulse.com/home.
 
So I guess the first step would be to find a good open source cms, and a service similar to the social media management and then find a programer to piece it all together.

Comment: @Lucky: Why would strapping an addition CMS onto Wordpress make things easier for the user? It'll require them to learn an additional system unless you do some heavy modification to the backend to integrate both the WP blog and the extra CMS into one interface. The only advantage to that approach, IMO, is when you need a CMS for a site that is too different from a standard blog to shoehorn it into WP.